# TextInputLayout endIcon is hiding Stroke or border

Tags: android, material-components-android

This is what is happening
[image]

I was following this article [Exposed Drop-Down Menu in Android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exposed-drop-down-menu-in-android/)

This is the code that I wrote

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:text="Choose Programming language" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

After digging into the problem I found out that if I delete

```xml
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
```

in my **theme.xml** the problem gets solved. The end icon no longer hides the border. But since I am using this attribute in my project so I can not remove it. I even tried to set the background transparent or @null in both TextInoutLayout and AutoCompleteTextView, nothing happened though.

One last thing this situation won't occur in **EditText** if I use **drawableEnd**

Comment: You usually don't want to specify `android:background` in your overall theme. That's setting the default background for every single `View` in the `Activity`, even ones you're not creating, like the `ImageView` that's being used for the down arrow. Even if you were to fix it in this one spot, you're likely to run into the same problem elsewhere, repeatedly. However, if you really do need to keep it like it is, you can set an `android:theme` attribute on the `<TextInputLayout>` to specify a theme without that background setting.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, I'm actually using that attribute because I have the dark theme in my app as well. I believe then I have to specify this attribute if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean, exactly, but themes always have all their default values set already. You're not required to set any additional attributes, unless you want to change a default setting. If you're saying that you're intentionally changing everything in the dark theme to have a white background by default, are you sure you really want a dark theme to begin with? I don't know your exact setup, though, so that may very well make more sense for your situation. Just pointing it out.

Comment: @MikeM. What I mean was, as per my knowledge (I'm a junior developer) I have to specify `<item name="android:background">@color/dark</item>` in my night theme.xml if I want the whole app to have that specific dark shade, and `<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>` in case of day theme. Because there is no other way, if I am not wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not sure what you mean. As mentioned, all themes already have all of their default values set already. If you have those attribute settings there in order to solve some other problem, I don't know what that would be. I don't think any system or Jetpack themes set `android:background` at all, so you shouldn't need to override anything.

Comment: @MikeM. okay, so where should I put the @color/dark if I want my app to have the same dark background color in dark mode? In my case the color is #181818

Comment: Are you talking about the whole `Activity` window? Did you mean to set `android:windowBackground` instead?

Comment: Many many thanks @MikeM. yeah, the problem is now solved. I was making this silly mistake. Thanks